# Shortest path with Bellman & Ford algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to implement Shortest path with Bellman & Ford algorithm. my idea is I use adjacent matrix

to save the information of digraph. If I want to find the shorest path of vertex i ,then I observe in-

degree of vertex i by the ith column of adjacent matrix ,and I save the shortest value of ith column

to a variable **"min"**.if I want to find the shorest path from source vertex v to vertex i.

I only **compare distance[i] with (distance[j]+ min )**, because "min" is equal to adjmatrix[j][i].

In addition, I make the traverse(source, k) function to comfirm which vertex we can reach it in k

steps and use the data structure stack to save information of vertex i. I assume to that i'll get  all the

shortest path from source vertex v to every vertex o graph except v itself. But the consequence after

compiling isn't that I expected. I finally got distance[i], 0 <= i < MAX_VERTEX, 1000,-1, 5, 5, 0 ,1000,

1000, respectively. What is my problem? Thanks for answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_VERTEX 7
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#define MAX_DISTANCE_LIMIT 1000
#define MAX_STACK_LENGTH 100

#define MIN(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? x : y)

int stack[MAX_STACK_LENGTH];
int top = -1; //pointer to top of stack.  
int adjmatrix[MAX_VERTEX][MAX_VERTEX];
short found[MAX_VERTEX];  //traverse(v ,k) : reach the vertex i By taking the k steps at most  
int distance[MAX_VERTEX]; //save the shortest path that source v to every vertex i

int init_matrix(void);
void BellmanFord(int v); //v is source
void traverse(int v,int times);
void push(int vertex);
int pop(void);

int main(void){
    
    int i,j;
    
    init_matrix(); //initial matrix and found[] array
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < MAX_VERTEX; j++)
            printf("%2d ", adjmatrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    BellmanFord(0);
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++)
        printf("%4d ", i);
    printf("\n");
        
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++)
        printf("%4d ", distance[i]);
    
    return 0;
}

int init_matrix(void){
    int num_edge = 0, i, j, w;
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++){
        found[i] = FALSE;
        for(j = 0; j < MAX_VERTEX; j++)
            adjmatrix[i][j] = MAX_DISTANCE_LIMIT; //set a large value to the entry of the vertice which aren't adjacent
    }
    
    while(1){
        printf("enter the vertices and weight of edge connected between them(w,tail,head): ");
        scanf("%d%d%d", &w, &i, &j);
        if((i >= MAX_VERTEX) || (j >= MAX_VERTEX)){
            fprintf(stderr, "index if the matrix should be less than %d");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(w == 0) break;
        
        adjmatrix[i][j] = w;
        num_edge++;
    }
    return num_edge;
}

void BellmanFord(int v){//compute all shortest path from v to every vertex ,and allow edge is negative
    int i, k, min = MAX_DISTANCE_LIMIT, j, minpos;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++)
        distance[i] = adjmatrix[v][i]; //value of dist"1"
    
    for(k = 2; k <= MAX_VERTEX - 1; k++){
        traverse(v,k); //traverse(v ,k)will set found[i] that we can reach in k steps TRUE.
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++ ){
            if( found[i] == FALSE)
                continue;
            for(j = 0; j < MAX_VERTEX; j++)
                if(adjmatrix[j][i]+distance[j] < min) {
                    min = adjmatrix[j][i]+distance[j];
                    minpos = j;
                }
            distance[i] = MIN(distance[i],adjmatrix[minpos][i]+distance[j]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++ ) //initial found array to FALSE
            found[i] = FALSE;
    }
}
void traverse(int v,int times){
    int i, next_order ,count = 0;
    
    if (times == 0) return ;
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++){
        if((adjmatrix[v][i] != MAX_DISTANCE_LIMIT) && (!found[i])){
            found[i] = TRUE;
            if(times == 1)
                return;
            push(i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        next_order = pop();
        traverse(next_order,times-1);
    }

    return;
}

void push(int vertex){
    if(top >= MAX_STACK_LENGTH){
        fprintf(stderr, "The stack is full.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    stack[++top] = vertex;
}
int pop(void){
    if(top == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "The stack is empty.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        return stack[top--];
}

/************************************
*graph information (w,tail,head)
input
6 0 1
5 0 2
5 0 3
-1 1 4
1 2 4
-2 2 1
-2 3 2
-1 3 5
3 5 6
3 4 6
0 0 0 //end the input
************************************
adjmatrix:

0  6  5  5  0  0  0
0  0  0  0 -1  0  0
0 -2  0  0  1  0  0
0  0 -2  0  0 -1  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  3
0  0  0  0  0  0  3
0  0  0  0  0  0  0

**************************************/
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you expected, what you go and what you did to fix it ?

Comment: I want to get the shortest path from source v to  every  vertex i of graph, but finally i get ∞,-1, 5, 5, 0 ,∞,∞. the answer should be ∞, 1, 3, 5, 0, 4, 3. I 'm not clear what is the problem of my think.